# How to enable 2 finger right click in kde plasma with touchpad

Tags: arch-linux, kde, touchpad, plasma

By default in kde plasma, clicking ( number of finger irrelevant ) the touchpad converts to a left click. How can I convert a 2 finger click to a right click?

At the moment I've modified my touchpad settings (`system-settings` -> `touchpad` -> `two finger tap` -> `right-click` ) so that a 2 finger tap is a right click, and this works well. Deep clicking in the bottom right portion of the touchpad also works.

however this is not what I'm looking for.

What I'm looking for is a deep click (where you can hear the click on the touchpad) with 2 fingers to be converted to a right click, much like most macOS and windows handles it.

This isn't a driver issue, I'm moving from gnome to kde plasma and this functionality works out of the box.

Comment: Just a FYI. There is a `libinput-gestures` that provides a lot more to gesture controls than the builtin one, you may give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dumb. In the touchpad menu there is clearly an option for what I'm looking for...

`system-settings` -> `touchpad` -> `right-click` -> `press anywhere with two fingers`

Comment: Hello, it seems this option was moved somewhere else since that. Since this is the only question I can find on this, did you perhaps in the meantime find that option again?

Comment: It's still in the same spot, my configs -> `kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.15.2
KDE Frameworks: 5.91.0
kf5-config: 1.0` and `plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.24.2`